# React: What would be a recommended way to cache state of the app in the browser to minimize the amount of requests to the backend?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, caching, redux, browser-cache

At my current work I came across an issue where it seems that the application is making some extra requests that I believe can be avoided and the app optimized for better performance.

Our *tech stack* is: **Typescript + React + Redux** (regular one, not Redux-Toolkit)

I would like to have the following outcomes:

1. The same dependancy value should not cause re-render of the page and make a new request to the backend
2. When user switches between the pages of the application coming back to a previously opened page makes a complete set of the same requests each time this page is opened.

For the (1) issue as far as I know I can do some optimization using **useMemo** and **useCallback**, however trying to find a suitable solution for (2) issue I came across a wide variety of options: from setting up some logic manually or using some wrappers to create a cache with Session Storage or IndexedDB in the browser to such solutions as **Redux-Toolkit + RTK Query**, **React Query**, **SWR**, **Redux-Persist**, etc.

What approach would you recommend me to pursue? I would say I understand that it requires quite significant changes in code and refactoring, so even more complicated solutions would fit greatly as long as they are more sustainable long term and easier to reuse.

As I understood Redux-Toolkit + RTK Query and React Query are exactly can be used for the purpose of caching and highly sustainable, would it be correct? Which one out of those 2 would be a recommended option?

Would using something like Redux-Persist suffice? As I understand it allows caching to session storage and in my case is most likely what I need. A state should be preserved as long as the page was opened in the browser and no dependencies have been changed.

Answer (score 2):

The app will make requests wherever necessary, caching does not stop that, it just fastens things up by providing locally stored data.

There is no caching to be obtained via redux or toolkit, it is just a predictable state manager.

Using a powerful data fetching tool like rtk query, react query will help, providing powerful cache management.

Manual caches are hard to handle. Session storage cache will have to be minified, encrypted and would require heavy cache busting and updation.